# passing button ID to post. js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table and each rows in a table have delete button with UNIQUE ID, what I am doing is onclick of the button post to delete.jsp page which runs the query to delete. What I need is onlcik pass the UNIQUE ID of button clicked to post so query can match ID in DB and delete that row. I am sorry if I am not clear enough please look at the code below for more explanation. any help will be greatly appreciated.[image]

```js
function{
//dynamically generating table which (have rows and one of the columns have buttons to delete)
//each dynamically generated button has unique ID coming from DB
//button is created inside js function
//each table row have buttons with uinqe ID


for eg: 
'<input type="button" id="each unique ID from db" class="dingdong">'

}

//now i am using onclick function to delete the row

   $(".dingdong").click(function() {
   $.post("testdelete.jsp", {
      //i need to pass each Unique ID(ID of the button which was clicked) to this post 
    id 
   }, function(data) {

   });

  });
    
    //in testdelet.jsp i have this query
    //Delete *from testdb where ID=?
```

Comment: Use `id:this.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event listener you can get the clicked jquery element using `$(this)`:

```
$(".dingdong").click(function() {
  var element = $(this);
  var parent = element.parent();
  // detach button from dom, so it can't be clicked twice
  element.detach();
  $.post("testdelete.jsp", {
    id: element.attr('id');
  }, function(data) {
    // on success remove the dom element representing your object.
    // I'm guessing you display the data in some sort of table
    element.remove();
    parent.closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: I thought this code will do it but it just hides the button which I click, I need to pass ID of the clicked button to post and that will do it for me. but I am unable to pass the ID of the clicked button to post.

Comment: sorry I missed something earlier, this is working perfect for me. Thanks a lot Patrick

Answer (score 0):

In your click event handler, the element that was clicked can be accessed via `this` keyword and its id via the `id` attribute

```
$.post("testdelete.jsp", {id: this.id}, function(data) {

});
```